# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'

Tags: python, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
async def servers(ctx):
    servers = bot.guilds
    servers.sort(key=lambda x: x.member_count, reverse=True)
    await ctx.send("Servers")
    for x in servers[:20]:
        await ctx.send("**{}** | **{}** Members | Owned by {} | Created at {}".format(x.name, x.member_count, x.owner.display_name, x.created_at))
    y = 0
    for x in bot.guilds:
        y += x.member_count
    await ctx.send("**Count:**\n**Users:** **{}** | **Server Count:** | **{}**".format(y, len(bot.guilds)))
```

I keep getting the error 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'. I don't fully understand why I say this.

Comment: On what line are you getting the error?

Comment: wait ctx.send("**{}** | **{}** Members | Owned by {} | Created at {}".format(x.name, x.member_count, x.owner.display_name, x.created_at)) < this one

Comment: `x.owner` is `None`.

Comment: It's not clear what you don't understand about the error message you're getting. `x.owner` is returning `NoneType`, meaning `x` doesn't have an explicit value set for the `owner` attribute; similarly `NoneType` definitely won't have `display_name`. Where is `x` set?

Comment: How would I fix it because there is an owner in the server @Barmar

Comment: @esqew If it didn't have the attribute it would signal an `AttributeError`.

Comment: The documentation ( https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.owner ) states that the owner attribute is optional and may not always be set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using Discord **1.5** and have your `intents` set up correctly. The API docs explain how to do that: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html

Answer (score 1):

Check whether there's an owner when trying to get the name.

```
for x in servers[:20]:
    owner_name = x.owner.display_name if x.owner else "unknown"
    await ctx.send("**{}** | **{}** Members | Owned by {} | Created at {}".format(x.name, x.member_count, owner_name, x.created_at))
```